# Отправка формы без submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Здравствуйте подскажите пожалуйста как можно отправить такую форму

```
<form action='' method='post' id="сom" class="private" >
<select name='privacy' class="black">
<option value=''>Выбрать</option>
<option value="0"<?php if ($myrow2['privacy']==0) echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Да</option>
<option value="1"<?php if ($myrow2['privacy']==1) echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Нет</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onclick="komm();" value="ОТПРАВИТЬ">
</form>

<script>
    function komm(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "save_users.php?id=<?=$myrow2[id]?>",
            data: $("#сom").serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                $("#resultprivate").html(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    };
</script>
Без кнопки submit.
```

Comment: А что сейчас происходит при нажатии кнопки "ОТПРАВИТЬ"?

Comment: Идет отправка ajax в файл save_users.php
Делал так. 
OnChange='user_mode.submit();' Но отправка ajax уже не идет.

Comment: По идее она и сейчас должна отправляться. Я бы сделал примерно так.

    $("#com input[type=button]").click(function() {
        komm();
    });

Comment: Так, прошу прощения, не могу понять. Нужна ajax отправка этой формы или обычная?

Вы писали: "Идет отправка ajax в файл save_users.php", вы не этого разве добивались, создавая функцию komm?

Comment: @iterq Нет все работает замечательно но только если пользователь выбирает что то и нажимает на кнопку отправить, а мне нужно что бы шла отправка формы без кнопки, то есть пользователь выбрал что то и сразу пошла отправка в файл без нажатии кнопки.

Comment: юзай change http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("select.black").change(function() {
    alert("Changed!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="сom" class="private">
    <select name='privacy' class="black">
        <option value=''>Выбрать</option>
        <option value="0">Да</option>
        <option value="1">Нет</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" id="send_form" value="ОТПРАВИТЬ" />
</form>
```

вот тут я сделал alert на изменение, но вместо него вы просто можете написать komm(); и сработает отправка формы по изменению селекта